# How can I access to related object by string field name in Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

Usually when we need to use ActiveRecord related object, we write such code:

```rb
main_object.related_object
```

Where `main_object` is instance of `MainObject` class and `related_object` is instance of `RelatedObject` that connected to `MainObject` via `related_object_id` field:

```rb
class MainObject < ActiveRecord::Base
     :has_one => :related_object
end

class RelatedObject < ActiveRecord::Base
     :belongs_to => :main_object
end
```

Count of relations might be difference and more than one. Also my task supposes custom queries where I don't know which one relation will be used.

So, I want to get related object via its name, eg:

```rb
main_object.relations['related_object']
```

Is it possible in Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord?

Comment: i think it seems like polymorphism, but in back direction .... and in my vision it is not currently possible with just rails, because in order to generate a proper query rails dont know name of a model to relate

Comment: But could you explain the task, you don't know a model name of relation, or you dont know just a fixed relation name?

Comment: Yes, I don't know fixed relation name
Model can have several relations, and different relations will be used in different cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [public_send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send)

`main_object.public_send(:related_object)`

Comment: Thanks, but `public_send`doesn't help with relations :(

Comment: Yes, it does.  `has_many` `belongs_to` e.t.c are just class methods that will add instance methods to the class.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It works, I did use it wrong first time - put square brackets instead round. But thanks my mistake I found another solution that described in answer!

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord` objects has `association` method returns association information for name.
It return [ActiveRecord::Associations::*](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations) class instance that contains `target` method:

```
association = main_object.association :related_object
association.target # returns RelatedObject instance that I wanted
```